# Get menu tail arguments of node route

Tags: 8, routes

I saw in [this post](https://drupal.org/node/1827544) that D8 does not support the passing of extra menu arguments. Several posts on DA gives workable solutions, but they don't fit this use case.

The contrib module I am porting depends heavily on using those the extra arguments passed to on the route `/node/1/my_thing`. Adding my_route causes a page_not_found error.

`my_thing` is not a tab but a parameter that generates content to merged into the view of the node.

As far as I know I cannot alter the behavior of core's route `entity.node.canonical`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

So in my case the route entity.node.canonical is not defined by my own module and although I want to use it in my module with an extra parameter, I don't want to mess with it.

I have chosen to use a query parameter (using ?) instead.

```
http://example.com/node/{nid}?id={id}
```

if you need the id you can get it from the request object:

```
$id = \Drupal::request()->query->get('id')
```